# How did a Greek 'table' become an English 'trapeze'?

Tags: etymology, greek

I had cause to investigate the word *trapeza* in Greek and I was intrigued as to how it had evolved into the meaning of 'trapeze' as we use it in modern English.

How did this happen ?

Comment: That was an interesting read; thank you for posting (+1). With the Q&A nature of the site, though, you might be better off splitting the post into two parts, posting just the question in the question box, with perhaps a hint of the oddity in translation, and the developed answer as your own answer below. You can even mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: 'Parallelograms' are classed as a subset of trapeziums in maths; the corresponding defininition for _trapezium_ is 'a quadrilateral with at least one pair of [opposite] sides parallel'. And of course 'a four sided figure with two sets of parallel sides' does not have to be a rectangle.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you. Edited, as above.

Comment: As Lawrence says, this should be split up into a question part and an answer part to fit the format properly. It shouldn’t be difficult to do this, just copy-paste most of it into the answer box and tweak the question itself a little to be formed as an actual question. (Also note that it is now fairly generally accepted that _τράπεζα_ in fact comes from _*tr̥-ped-ih₂_ ‘three-legs’, rather than _*kʷtu̯r̥-ped-ih₂_ ‘four-legs’, but that doesn’t really change much in terms of the resulting shape. The specific ‘counter’ mean is only Modern Greek, though; in Ancient Greek it was just any table.)

Comment: Note that indeed in modern Greek, _τράπεζα_ has indeed a restricted meaning of _counter_ or _bank_, but _τραπέζι_ means simply _table_.

Comment: Possibly related - [Isoseles Trapezium Linkage](https://books.google.com/books?id=m1ntVvPWRtoC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=four+bar+linkage+%22trapezium%22&source=bl&ots=o5WOMpzCJx&sig=ACfU3U09AEymkn3zqVxcvguQaJh8fykOqA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-7dbgr4zkAhUS0KwKHUaYB54Q6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=four%20bar%20linkage%20%22trapezium%22&f=false). See chapter 5 starting on page 70. The term trapezium wasn't just a four sided figure. It came to refer to a linkage with four bars connected with pivots. This happened at least 50 years before the trapeze was named.

Comment: As advised by Lawrence and @JanusBahsJacquet, I have re-posted a brief question and answered it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From *tetra*, four, and *peza*, 'foot' (in the sense of extremity) comes the Greek word *trapeza* meaning 'table' which can be precisely translated 'counter' in English as the noun is always used in Greek as a service table for serving food or as a surface upon which to handle coinage in banking.

Greek mathematicians (led by Euclid) then used the 'four-legged' sense in geometry to denote four-sided figures, such that we, in English, refer to one which has no parallels as a 'trapezoid' and to a four-sided figure which has one set of parallels as a 'trapezium'.

(A four sided figure with two sets of parallels is a parallelogram, which, if the angles are right angles, will be a rectangle.)

Since a 'table' or a 'counter' does not necessarily have to be square on top (the servant's side is actually better to be shorter than the customer's side) the word *trapeza* denotes, in Greek, any four sided figure.

> 1570   H. Billingsley tr. Euclid Elements Geom. i. f. 5v   All other figures of foure sides besides these, are called trapezia, or tables.

When a wooden handle is suspended from a sloping ceiling (in a hall or a circus marquee) then the arrangement forms a trapezium (one set of parallel sides) - as seen in the inset of the picture below - and this arrangement is called a trapeze .

> 1830   Encycl. Brit. XI. 350/2   The trapeze consists of a horizontal bar suspended by ropes at a height of 4 or 5 feet from the floor.

But there is also another arrangement when a sailor on board a small yacht or dinghy leans out from the side, suspended by a 'trapeze' in order to lean the vessel into the wind - as in the main picture below. Strictly speaking the figure displayed here (by the deck, the sailor's body, the line to the mast and the mast itself) is a trapezoid since there are no parallels and it is completely irregular.

> 1961   F. H. Burgess Dict. Sailing 211   Trapeze, in sailing dinghies, a sliding support used by the crew for outboard balancing when they lay up to windward.

[image]

Comment: 'Trapeze' means most canonically to me the circus act. I was expecting that to be the point of discussion, the 'modern' meaning. Where does that fit in?

Comment: @Mitch - see the 1830 quote in the answer

Comment: @Henry That description is pretty uninformative to me. But the one from etymonline says everything: " [trapeze (n.)
swing with a cross-bar, used for feats of strength and agility, 1861, from French trapèze, from Late Latin trapezium (see trapezium), probably because the crossbar, the ropes and the ceiling formed a trapezium.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/trapeze)

Comment: @Mitch I would have thought the four sides were obvious, and 1830 (if correct) is earlier than 1861

Comment: @Henry It's not obvious at all to me. I've never considered the ropes and bar to be a shape, and if forced to consider them as such, I think of it as a long thin rectangle. Full disclosure: I am not a professional circus clown.